# Pass a property of the model to the template in ItemView

Tags: marionette

I want to pass a property of my model to the template, so I presume I need a serializeData function, I tried this

```
serializeData:function(){
    return this.model.toJSON().extend({_schema:this.model.schema});
}
```

but it complained about not being able to extend the output of toJSON. This must be a standard trick, stick some value from the prototype into the serialised form so the template can get it's hands on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`templateHelpers`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.view.html#viewtemplatehelpers) for this use case – `serializeData` works better for replacing the model attributes entirely, or scoping them down.

```
templateHelpers: function()
{
    return { _schema: this.model.schema };
}
```

Comment: Ok. Well I'll add a helper to handlebars then called '%' which will take an argument and return this.model [arg]

Comment: @MarkLester Not sure what Handlebars helpers has to do with this. Marionette’s `templateHelpers` is just a convenient way to add to the attributes hash passed to the template – just badly named.

Comment: Yes. I withdraw that.

Answer (score 0):

Harladson's answers is the best, but in case someone else comes looking different approach you can do this:

```
serializeData:function(){
    var data = this.model.toJSON();
    data._schema = this.model.schema;
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I guess what I want is to be able to go {{#each %schema}} , which would be nice but hard. Template helper is the way to keep me going